# How to verify if given numbers from a file are in an arithmetic progression?

Tags: c++

Basically what I want to do is to verify if the numbers : 180 30 80 280 130 330 230 30 30 330 80 are in an arithmetic progression and to find the ratio. I tried using the following algorithm but even if I insert 35 into the row (which is not correct) the answer is 50 instead of NO.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x, fr[1000]={0} ,r=0 , ok=0, i, v[100], j=0;
    ifstream f("bac.in");
    while(f>>x)
        fr[x]++;
    for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
    {
        if(fr[i]!=0) // I search for the first frequency and only then start to count 
        ok=0;
        else ok=1;

    if(ok==0)
        r++; // ratio
        else {v[j++]=r; r=0;} // if another frequency was found, ratio is reseted
    }

    for(i=0;i<j-1;i++) // i verify if every ratio is equal in this for
    {
        if(v[i]==v[i+1])
            ok=1;
        else ok=0;
    }
    if(ok==1)
        cout<<++v[i];
        else cout<<"NO";
    f.close();
}
```

My idea was to find the numbers of 0's between frequencies and to count that as the ratio and put it into an array where I would verifiy if the ratios are equal. If I missed any piece of information please tell me.
It has to be done in an efficient way, so putting the numbers into an array, sorting it, deleting the doubled numbers and only after that finding the ratio (if there is any) is out of the discussion.

Comment: Not sure what you mean (as for me, arithmetic progression would satisfy `U[n+1] - U[n] == k`, so for `180 30 80`, `180 - 30 != 30 - 80` so wrong).

Comment: @Jarod42 Wild guess, data are to be sorted and make unique first...

Comment: In this case numbers aren't ordered. So I can't use U[n+1] - U[n] since that could be 30 - 80. As I said, "It has to be done in an efficient way, so putting the numbers into an array, sorting it, deleting the doubled numbers and only after that finding the ratio (if there is any) is out of the discussion."

Comment: Do you realize that if you store only the unique data sorted, all you have to do is verify if the values are at the same distance between each others?

Comment: sort/unique is the right way. If you know your entries, count_sort allow the sort+unique at once.

Comment: Your last loop set `ok` according to last `v[i]`, `v[i + 1]` comparison.

Comment: Ok but how do I store the data from the file bac.in into an array to be unique and sorted at the same time ?

Comment: Are there some constraints over those values? Depending if it's rather very very big file with only few values (many are repeating), or the values are from limited range (probably yes, as you do `fr[1000]` only), or the input file is not that big, but ranges are huge.... you can focus on different algorithms. With reasonable size of input and unlimited ranges, some kind of building binary tree may be better (to end with sorted array), then just checking differences.

Comment: @Phux From the docs: "[std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is an associative container that contains a sorted set of unique objects of type Key." Just push all your values into an std::set and then you're done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to accomplish this. Set guarantees no duplicates and also keeps your data sorted! This means you just have to toss everything into the set and then iterate over once to check the differences.

An insertion into the set costs you `O(log(n))` and we're doing `n` of them so that'll be `O(nlog(n))`. Afterwards, we loop the set to check if we have a progression or not, so that'll be another `O(n)` giving us complexity `O(nlog(n) + n) = O(nlog(n))`. Is that fast enough for you?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::set<int> values;
    int x;
    while (std::cin >> x) { //replace cin with your file handler
        values.insert(x);
    }

    int difference = 0;
    bool good = true;
    for(auto it = values.begin(); it != values.end() && std::next(it) != values.end(); it++) {
        if(!difference) difference = *it - *std::next(it);
        else if(difference != *it - *std::next(it)) good = false;
    }

    if(good) {
        std::cout << "We have a progression!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "No go on the progression." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

See it in action [here](https://ideone.com/z0X7dt) (ideone link).

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in the last loop, which should be:

```
bool ok = true;
for (int i = 0; i < j - 1; ++i) // i verify if every ratio is equal in this for
{
    if (v[i] != v[i+1]) {
        ok = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

or

```
ok = (j == 0 || std::all_of(v, v + j, [&](int e) { return e == v[0]; }));
```

Fixed code:

```
std::vector<int> values {180, 30, 80, 280, 130, 330, 230, 30, 30, 330, 80 };
int fr[1000]={0};
for (auto e : values)
    fr[e]++;
int j = 0;
int v[100];
int r = 0;
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++)
{
    if(fr[i] == 0)
        r++; // ratio
    else {
        v[j++]=r;
        r=0;
    } // if another frequency was found, ratio is reseted
}

bool ok = true;
for (int i = 1; i < j - 1; ++i) // i verify if every ratio is equal in this for
{
    if (v[i] != v[i+1]) {
        ok = false;
        break;
    }
}
if(ok==1)
    std::cout << v[1] + 1;
else
    std::cout<<"NO";
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/CCGQse).

Comment: Now there's nothing showing up, not even "no" or ++v[i]. 
I'm literally stomped by this...

Comment: Note that `v[0]` should be also ignored as it is wrong (progression from 0 to first `fr[i] != 0`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `O(n)` solution:

- It iterates over the list finding the smallest, second smallest and largest elements. (It does this with three seperate iterations, but it could be one loop with a little more code.)
- Denoting these *x*<sub>0</sub>, *x*<sub>1</sub>, and *x*<sub>n</sub>, assuming there is an arithmetic progression we can now figure out the difference (*c* = *x*<sub>1</sub> - *x*<sub>0</sub>) and total number of elements (*n*+1 = (*x*<sub>n</sub> - *x*<sub>0</sub>)/*c*).
- We create an array of booleans of length *n*+1 and start marking off the present elements. If any don't fall into this pattern we immediately return false. At the end, we check that all the elements have been marked false.

By the way, I consider @scohe001's answer to be better. It is slightly slower, but it is more obvious that it is correct and *that* is what is really important, unless you have tried it and found that it really is too slow. If you're only dealing with a few hundred thousand elements or less, the time difference is unlikely to be noticable, especially if you're also having to read the elements from a file, which is likely to be much slower than this stage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdlib.h>

int conditionalMin(const std::vector<int>& numbers, int lowerBound)
{
    int result = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    for (int x : numbers) {
        if (x < result && x > lowerBound) {
            result = x;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

bool isArithmeticSet(const std::vector<int>& numbers)
{
    // Look for smallest, second smallest, and largest numbers
    int x0 = *std::min_element(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());
    int x1 = conditionalMin(numbers, x0);
    int xn = *std::max_element(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    // Find which elements are present (exit early if any inappropriate elements)
    int sequenceCount = (xn - x0) / (x1 - x0) + 1;
    boost::dynamic_bitset<> present(sequenceCount);
    for (int x : numbers) {
        div_t divResult = div(x - x0, x1 - x0);
        if (divResult.rem != 0 || divResult.quot < 0 || divResult.quot > sequenceCount) {
            return false;
        }
        present[divResult.quot] = true;
    }

    // Are all the required elements present?
    return present.all();
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> numbers = {180, 30, 80, 280, 130, 330, 230, 30, 30, 330, 80 };

    std::cout << "is an arithmetic set: " << isArithmeticSet(numbers) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```